# Regex Find and Replace in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to find and replace following

```
rice', ' 36,650', 'https://s
va', ' 3,650', 'https://s
rat', ' 332,650', 'https://s
fe', ' 34,650', 'https://s
rfce', ' 13,650', 'https://s
aace', ' 53,650', 'https://s
```

to

```
rice', '36650', 'https://s
va', '3650', 'https://s
rat', '332650', 'https://s
fe', '34,650', 'https://s
rfce', '13650', 'https://s
aace', '53650', 'https://s
```

Removing one comma and space from the start of digit

Update

It is not working with this one

```
(9, 'M-MG1', 'httion', 'Buyice', ' 3,650', 'https://', 4, 'February 22, 2016', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this replace : `' ([0-9]+),([0-9]+)'` with `\1\2`

Comment: the space does not appear in your answer. Maybe is it because it's a the start of your code inline block? You can use &nbsp instead of space to fix that.

Comment: What space are you talking about @Aaron ?

Comment: The one mentionned in the question, that OP wants to remove

Comment: It help and solved my problem I used `'\s([0-9]+),([0-9]+)'` to remove the space

Comment: Yeah thanks well &nbsp didn't work I tried `' ([0-9]+),([0-9]+)'` and it worked `'\s([0-9]+),([0-9]+)'` is working as well :).

Comment: Actually it's `&nbsp;` ; anyway matching the quotes provides additional confidence you're matching what you want

Answer (score 1):

Search `' (\d+),(\d+)'`, replace by `'\1\2'`.

Explanation :

- `\d` is a digit
- `\d+` is one or more digits. It will match as many digits as it can.
- `(\d+)` is a group containing one or more digits
- `\1` and `\2` are back-references : they reference the previously defined groups

Comment: I just tried it and it worked. Did you select the regex search mode?

Comment: It is working with the above example but not with this (Updated Question)

Comment: it's still working for me, the `' 3,650'` is changed into `'3650'`

Comment: If it helps, here's an illustration of the code in regex101 : https://regex101.com/r/lP6hJ0/1